# Problems due to having too many single PSUs at stage one

Tags: r, survey

I am calculating the anthropometric failure prevalence for 25 countries with r-studio and the package survey.
For 24 countries it worked fine. But for India I get illogical values.
I get an underweight prevalence for India 2016 of 20.8%(18.4%-23.1%) according to statcompiler it should be 35.7%. 
When I calculate it manually then I get a value of 34.8%, however I need the standard error for my analysis so I have to consider the complex study design with the package survey in R. I get the error message: Error in onestrat(x[index, , drop = FALSE], clusters[index], nPSU[index][1],  : 
  Stratum (5610) has only one PSU at stage 1 ,

I tried various things first I excluded manually the observations for which only one PSU at stage 1 was available and then I tried the command options(survey.lonely.psu="remove"), (I also tried "adjust" and "average"). The first approach gives me even worse results than the lonely.psu approach.

```
IN16_final<- IN16_final[ which(IN16_final$waz<+5 & IN16_final$waz >= -6),]

# categorize underweight in children 
IN16_final$Category[IN16_final$waz <=-3                                      ] = "2"#severly underweight"
IN16_final$Category[IN16_final$waz <= -2 & IN16_final$waz >= -3] = "1"#moderately underweight"
IN16_final$Category[IN16_final$waz >-2                                       ] = "0"#not underweight"

#dummy for underweight or not underweight
IN16_final$wazcat<-ifelse(IN16_final$waz>=-2,0,1)# 0 not underweight, 1 underweight


#manual exclusion of values that have only one obs for PSU stage 1
IN16_final<- IN16_final[IN16_final$v023 != "912",]

#alternative
options(survey.lonely.psu="remove")

#result for India 2016
                      mean     SE
#underweight_prevalence 0.20776 0.0119
```

Comment: maybe use `options(survey.lonely.psu="adjust")`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! But as I wrote I already tried "adjust" and "average" as well. Somehow if I don't include the weights in the survey design I get the "official" results.

Answer (score 4):

This is quite an old post, hope you found a work-around already.
Today I had the same question and for me this worked out:

```
options(survey.adjust.domain.lonely=TRUE)
options(survey.lonely.psu="adjust")
```

source:
https://r-survey.r-forge.r-project.org/survey/exmample-lonely.html

Comment: This was a lifesaver, thank you!